# Cannot create abstract addition operation for GADT in Z3

Tags: python, z3, z3py

**Problem**

I'm working with the following `Datatype` definitions in Z3. My objective is to essentially "overload" the addition operator. I tried the following trick using `ForAll`, but Z3 seems to think it is invalid.

**Question**

What is going on? Why doesn't this work?

**Code**

```
import pytest
from z3 import Datatype, IntSort, Solver, Ints

def test_stackoverflow():
    FooBar = Datatype('FooBar')
    FooBar.declare('foo', ('unfoo', IntSort()))
    FooBar.declare('bar', ('unbar', FooBar))
    FooBar.declare('plus', ('left', FooBar), ('right', FooBar))
    FooBar = FooBar.create()

    foo = FooBar.foo
    unfoo = FooBar.unfoo
    bar = FooBar.bar
    unbar = FooBar.unbar
    plus = FooBar.plus

    solver = Solver()
    x, y = Ints('x y')
    solver.add(ForAll[x, y], plus(foo(x), foo(y)) == foo(x + y))
    assert str(solver) == "sat"
```

This doesn't pass as the result is "unsat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is `unsat`, because you essentially said:

```
  forall x, y => foo (x+y) = plus (foo x, foo y)
```

This is obviously wrong because `foo` and `plus` are two different constructors for your datatype, and thus regardless of what you pass they will never be equal. Note that the datatypes are freely generated: Each constructor defines a different value.

I suspect what you're trying to say is that `plus` generates some "number" like thing such that `foo (x+y) = plus (foo x, foo y)` holds. If that's the case, then do *not* make `plus` a constructor. Instead, make it an uninterpreted function that takes a `FooBar` and produce an `Int`; and assert the above appropriately. In SMTLib notation, it would look something like:

```
(declare-datatypes ((FooBar 0)) (((foo (unfoo Int)) (bar (unbar FooBar)))))
(declare-fun plus (FooBar FooBar) Int)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int)) (= (plus (foo x) (foo y)) (unfoo (foo (+ x y))))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Alas, while this is perfectly good coding, z3 simply goes out to lunch on it:

```
$ z3 -v:3 a.smt2
... many lines of verbose output showing quantifier instantiation ...
```

The e-matching engine is just having a very hard time finding a model in this case. Of course, if you have extra constraints you might get a useful result, or you can try patterns to help z3. But, in my experience, none of that is really going to really work as quantifiers simply make the problem too difficult for the current SMT-solving technology.

NB. There's a minor typo in your program, second to last line should say:

```py
    solver.add(ForAll([x, y], plus(foo(x), foo(y)) == foo(x + y)))
```

(Note the parentheses.)