# Solving Tabular relations

Tags: z3, z3py

In scenario :
Input table with columns "Name", "Value"

- Each column is represented as Enum sorts for z3 (Valid possible values of a column is known)
- A combination (Name, Value) is represented as a DataType
- Valid combination : if it appears in table

The following sample code always returns unsat.
I can model same using uninterpreted sort and functions, however would like to know why the following with DataType isnt working.

```py
import z3 as z3

symbol_dict = {}

def create_enum_sort(name, elts):
    global symbol_dict
    z3_sort, z3_elts = z3.EnumSort(name, elts)
    for e in z3_elts:
        symbol_dict[str(e)] = e
    return z3_sort


# Universe of Enum values for columns to take
Values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
Names = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C5']

VTYPE = create_enum_sort('VTYPE', Values)
NTYPE = create_enum_sort('NTYPE', Names)

# Valid combinations (Table relation)
dct = {'A2': '2',
       'A1': '1',
       'B1': '1',
       'B2': '2',
       'C5': '5'}

# Record type consisting of Name, Value
comb = z3.Datatype('Comb')
comb.declare('cons', \
           ('value', VTYPE), \
           ('name', NTYPE) \
           )
COMB = comb.create()

# Constraint to valid combinations
constraints = []
e1 = z3.Const('e1', COMB)
for key, value in dct.items():
    constraints.append(z3.ForAll([e1], 
            z3.Implies(COMB.name(e1) == symbol_dict[key], COMB.value(e1) == symbol_dict[value])))
    

# Basic check 
solver = z3.Solver()
solver.add(constraints)

xvar = z3.Const('xvar', COMB)

solver.set(unsat_core=True)
print(solver.assertions())    
res = solver.check()
print(res)
if res == z3.sat:
    model = solver.model()
    print('Model:', model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is `unsat` because data-types in SMTLib are freely generated. If you look at the output of your program, you'll see:

```
ForAll(e1, Implies(name(e1) == A2, value(e1) == 2))
```

amongst other constraints. This constraint by itself isn't satisfiable. Why? Because it says for all `Comb` values, if the name field is `A2`, then it's value field must be `2`. Clearly that's not true: A freely generated data-type contains all those values; i.e., it also contains the value `name = A2` and `value = 1`. This is why you're getting `unsat`. (Note what your assertion is saying: *FOR ALL* values of `Comb`, it needs to satisfy the constraint. This is clearly not true.)

Of course, what you wanted to say was *not* that all `Comb` values satisfy this constraint! You meant there's a particular `Comb` that has these properties. The way to write that is as follows. I'm only including the part that modifies the `constraints` variable; everything prior can stay the same:

```py
constraints = []
e1 = z3.Const('e1', COMB)
for key, value in dct.items():
    constraints.append(z3.Implies(COMB.name(e1) == symbol_dict[key], COMB.value(e1) == symbol_dict[value]))

solver = z3.Solver()
solver.add(z3.Or(constraints))

solver.set(unsat_core=True)
res = solver.check()
print(res)
if res == z3.sat:
    model = solver.model()
    print('Model:', model.evaluate(e1, model_completion=True))
```

This prints:

```
sat
Model: cons(1, A1)
```

giving you one possible interpretation for the value of `e1`.

Note that I had to use the `evaluate` method of the model to get this printed. Simply printing the model returns an empty list; which can be surprising. I'm not entirely sure why z3 doesn't assign a value for it in the standard-mode. Model-construction has its own quirks. I suspect if you have other constraints on `e1` you wouldn't need to do so. If this turns out to be a hurdle, feel free to post a new question demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation above. It provided very useful insights. However the problem statement is exactly that : All instances of Comb. must satisfy the constraints. (Not find an instance of Comb. that satisfies the constraint). Is it possible to create kind-of constrained Datatype which implicitly specifies relational constraints between its constituents

Comment: As I mentioned, all datatypes are freely generated. So, you *cannot* create a data-type that has just those instances. The only way to do that would be to enumerate the values and make an (non-parameterized) enumeration. Datatypes, as you created them, are always freely generated and you cannot put any "value" constraints on them.

Comment: Here're two more questions on stack-overflow regarding how data-types behave in z3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452056/z3-modeling-graph-with-datatype-of-arrays/64452374#64452374 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593974/cannot-create-abstract-addition-operation-for-gadt-in-z3/54601400#54601400

Comment: Thanks for the help. Makes things clear. will explore the enumeration approach.

Comment: No problem; and welcome to the site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers on possible actions when you receive an answer on the site.